# Get stacktrace from error event

Tags: javascript, exception

I'm implementing a global exception handler which should log the exception and send information to the server. Right now my code looks like

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (errorEvent) {
  var errorLine = '';
  if (errorEvent.filename) {
    var lastSlashIndex = errorEvent.filename.lastIndexOf('/');
    errorLine += errorEvent.filename.substr(lastSlashIndex + 1);
  }
  if (errorEvent.lineno) errorLine += ':' + errorEvent.lineno;
  if (errorEvent.message) errorLine += ' ' + errorEvent.message;
```

So I can extract location where the exception was thrown, but not full stack trace. I investigated the error event which is passed to the event listener callback, but I didn't find any information about stack trace. Is it possible to get this information from the event listener callback?

I'm interested in solution for Safari mobile and Chrome mobile, but any other information is welcome, of course.